# How to force sails js csrf or login routes to always set response header set-cookie

Tags: http, cookies, sails.js

I'm working with sails.js, trying to get it to always set the `Set-Cookie` response header for either the /csrfToken or /api/v1/entrance/login routes, so my React Native app can always dependably set the cookie in the app, and use it in all subsequent authorized requests. sails.js seems to only set it on the first call to /csrfToken from my app, but not on any of the rest, despite sending identical headers every time. Does anyone know how I can force sails.js to always respond with set-cookie on either of these routes?

Answer (score 0):

You might use a hook for all the routes:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/hook-specification/routes

```js
module.exports = function (sails) {
  return {
    routes: {
      before: {
        'GET /*': function (req, res, next) {
          // check req.headers.cookie
          // set res.cookie()
          return next();
        }
      },
  }
}
```

req.cookies

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-cookies#req-cookies

res.cookie()

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-cookie#res-cookie-